# How do I add multiple Shapes.Path to ListView in WinRT XAML?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

I have a ListView control in XAML that has items Styled by below code (WinRT C#).
But I cannot display "path_2" looks like below image.

[image: Image ListView with multiple Shapes.Path, path_2 NOT Appearing]

How do I add multiple Shapes.Path to ListView in WinRT XAML?

[MainPage.xaml.cs]

```
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes;

namespace AppListViewPath
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            object o;
            Application.Current.Resources.TryGetValue("PathCustomStyle", out o);

            Path path_1 = new Path()
            {
                Style = (Style)o
            };

            Path path_2 = new Path()
            {
                Style = (Style)o
            };

            this.listView_path.Items.Add(path_1); // show
            this.listView_path.Items.Add(path_2); // doesn't show...
        }
    }
}
```

[App.xaml]

```
<Application
    x:Class="AppListViewPath.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:AppListViewPath"
    RequestedTheme="Light">

    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Common/StandardStyles.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

            <Style x:Key="PathCustomStyle" TargetType="Path">
                <Setter Property="Data" Value="M95,15 C95,20 95,20 95,20"/>
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="200"/>
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="200"/>
                <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="Red"/>
                <Setter Property="Stretch" Value="Fill"/>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            </Style>

        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

[MainPage.xaml]

```
<Page
    x:Class="AppListViewPath.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:AppListViewPath"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <ListView x:Name="listView_path"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you cannot use the same Geometry multiple times in the visual tree, and the style resolves the Path.Data reference to a Geometry when it reads it in rather than assigning the string to the target and resolving it then. Since the Geometry is already in use, the second Path ends up with no Data.

Instead of setting the Data directly in the Style you can create a String resource for the Data and set that separate from the style:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <Style x:Key="PathCustomStyle" TargetType="Path">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="200"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="200"/>
        <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="Red"/>
        <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="10" />
        <Setter Property="Stretch" Value="Fill"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    </Style>

    <x:String x:Key="PathDataString">M95,15 C95,20 95,20 95,20</x:String>
<ResourceDictionary>
```

To set in Xaml:

```
<Path Style="{StaticResource PathCustomStyle}" Data="{StaticResource PathDataString}" />
```

To set in code:

```
object o;
Application.Current.Resources.TryGetValue("PathCustomStyle", out o);

string stringData = (string)Application.Current.Resources["PathDataString"];

string xamlPath = "<Path xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'>" +
"<Path.Data>" + stringData + "</Path.Data></Path>";

// Shows 10
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    Path path = XamlReader.Load(xamlPath) as Path;
    path.Style = (Style)o;

    this.listView_path.Items.Add(path);
}
```